# Do I need to put NOT NULL when using AUTO_INCREMENT in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, auto-increment

I'm implementing a DB for a project I'm doing in my research and, after using some AUTO_INCREMENTS I got curious... Once the AUTO_INCREMENT is already automatically inserting a value in the column, why do we need to put the NOT NULL together?

Example:

```
user_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Thanks.

Comment: Because you can insert values into that column, even though it is `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: `null` inserted into an auto_inc field in mysql is a signal to replace that null with the actual next increment value. Plus, auto_inc fields tend to be primary keys, and a nullable primary key is not permitted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to specify `NOT NULL` on the column definition with `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

You can leave it off, and MySQL will make the column `NOT NULL`.

And if you specify `NULL` in place of `NOT NULL`, MySQL will accept the syntax, but it will ignore that, and make the column `NOT NULL` anyway.